# Are Aliens mentioned in Vedas?

Tags: vedas

As Stephen Hawking launches search for Aliens, I would like to know whether any of our Vedas have mentioned Aliens or any other living being living in different planet, who could be more intellectual than us. Please enlighten me.

Comment: What's your definition of aliens?

Comment: As per Wiki - "a hypothetical or fictional being from another world."

Comment: Hindu scriptures mentions 14 lokas (seven below, seven above). In all lokas there are "living things" are present, however, it forms may be different.  Alien word sounds negative, Hindu terminology it is all friendly souls in different mental plane.